# Autosize witdth of treeview after collapse

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

I'm looking for a way to set the width of a treeview to either it's max, or to the size of the longest treenode in it, whenever a node is being collapsed or opened.

I've tried using the clientsize, but that doesn't seem to work.
Is there a different way to check which node is the longest and set the TreeView.Width to that size?

Comment: Why not just do what the Windows shell does now, and have the TreeView automatically scroll horizontally based on the selected item and the position of the mouse cursor? I don't think it's really a good idea to dynamically *resize* controls; that can be very disorienting for users.

Comment: Thou what you say is true, I never stated that this project would be for public eyes.

Comment: Okay...? I'm not sure why it's any less true for you than it would be for everyone else. But whatever; you're entitled to design your app however I want, that's why I posted it as a comment, rather than an answer. Another reason to do it the way I suggested is that there's no particularly *easy* way to do what you're asking. The TreeView control doesn't have an `AutoSize` property for a reason. You're going to have to walk the nodes, check the length, determine which one is the longest, and then calculate the size of the control necessary to fit the longest node string.

Comment: Was working on that but I fail.  All aboard the failboat!
Based on your comment I changed my method to user-interactive instead of automatic.  which would mean, when the user clicks on a specific spot I wish for the control to auto size.  Walking throu the nodes would be a proper way to do it.  Please post that as a answer so I can accept it if there isn't a better in the meantime

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some more searching on the net I found this way:

```
private const int GWL_STYLE = -16;
private const int WS_VSCROLL = 0x00200000;
private const int WS_HSCROLL = 0x00100000;


[DllImport("user32.dll", ExactSpelling = false, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
private static extern int GetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex);
```

and:

```
//tree = instance of a treeview
tree.AfterExpand += (s, ea) =>
{
    int style = GetWindowLong(tree.Handle, GWL_STYLE);
    while ((style & WS_HSCROLL) != 0)
    {
        tree.Width++;
        style = GetWindowLong(tree.Handle, GWL_STYLE);
    }
};
```

Ofcourse you can use this on a button aswell!